# MariaDB High CPU load after Crash

Tags: central-processing-unit, mariadb, innodb

I have a problem with MariaDB 10.3.16. I was trying to convert a rather large table (26GB) from MyISAM to InnoDB and unfortunately the disk space ran out during this process. When it got full, it logged plenty messages like this:

`2022-03-25  0:03:54 18688637 [ERROR] InnoDB: preallocating 26935820288 bytes for file ./mydatabase/#sql-22ba_11d2a7d.ibd failed with error 28`

...and then MariaDB crashed. I freed up some space and started MariaDB again -> log said two tables crashed and they got checked. It ran a while, then the checking finished and everything seemed normal. Tables are up-to-date and usable. (that one table is still MyISAM of course)

Strangely though, since thenthe `mysqld` process is running on high CPU (around 75%) and doesn't seem to recover. The server had this high CPU usage for the last 24 hours now.
There are no abnormal queries running and I just don't know why it is eating up all the CPU.

I ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` which gave me this:

```
=====================================
2022-03-26 00:09:30 0x7ff7d80ab700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 16 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 51 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 989 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1040
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 5965
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1779
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 719, OS waits 286
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 61, OS waits 2
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 719.00 RW-shared, 61.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 13314188
Purge done for trx's n:o < 13314188 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 422177494315392, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422177494311176, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 422177494306960, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 10 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 11 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 12 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 13 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 14 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 15 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 16 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 17 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 18 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 19 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 20 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 21 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 22 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 23 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 24 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 25 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 26 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 27 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 28 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 29 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 30 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 31 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 32 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 33 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 34 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 35 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 36 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 37 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 38 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 39 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 40 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 41 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 42 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 43 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 44 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 45 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 46 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 47 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 48 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 49 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 50 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 51 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 52 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 53 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 54 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 55 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 56 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 57 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 58 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 59 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 60 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 61 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 62 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 63 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 64 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 65 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 66 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 67 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 68 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 69 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 70 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 71 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 72 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 73 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 74 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 75 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 76 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 77 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 78 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 79 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 80 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 81 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 82 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 83 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 84 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 85 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 86 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 87 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 88 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 89 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 90 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 91 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 92 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 93 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 94 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 95 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 96 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 97 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 98 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 99 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 100 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 101 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 102 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 103 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 104 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 105 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 106 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 107 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 108 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 109 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 110 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 111 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 112 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 113 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 114 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 115 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 116 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 117 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 118 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 119 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 120 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 121 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 122 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 123 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 124 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 125 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 126 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 127 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 128 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 129 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
8105 OS file reads, 503 OS file writes, 335 OS fsyncs
0.44 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 1.25 writes/s, 1.19 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 56, seg size 58, 7 merges
merged operations:
insert 7, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 21 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 6 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 32 buffer(s)
Hash table size 1593833, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
18.56 hash searches/s, 10.12 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 57880104793
Log flushed up to   57880104793
Pages flushed up to 57880104793
Last checkpoint at  57880104784
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
100 log i/o's done, 0.31 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 7127171072
Dictionary memory allocated 176256
Buffer pool size   393216
Free buffers       385734
Database pages     7418
Old database pages 2895
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 7287, created 131, written 293
0.44 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.50 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7418, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48320
Database pages     824
Old database pages 324
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 820, created 4, written 34
0.06 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 824, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48319
Database pages     825
Old database pages 324
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 825, created 0, written 20
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 825, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48199
Database pages     945
Old database pages 368
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 945, created 0, written 16
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 945, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48081
Database pages     1063
Old database pages 412
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1063, created 0, written 28
0.06 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1063, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48163
Database pages     981
Old database pages 382
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 981, created 0, written 31
0.06 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.12 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 998 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 981, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48201
Database pages     943
Old database pages 368
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 943, created 0, written 18
0.06 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 943, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48130
Database pages     1014
Old database pages 394
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 951, created 63, written 73
0.06 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 998 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1014, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   49152
Free buffers       48321
Database pages     823
Old database pages 323
Modified db pages  0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 759, created 64, written 73
0.12 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.06 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 991 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 823, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=1957, Main thread ID=140695161886464, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 15, updated 1, deleted 0, read 1046108
0.06 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 1589.46 reads/s
Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

The `FILE I/O` section looks rather suspicious with all those `I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests`, but I don't really know what to do with this information?

A server restart didn't help, CPU is still high and won't go down:

```
Tasks: 117 total,   1 running, 116 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 72.2 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16266120 total, 13867856 free,  1429552 used,   968712 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2047996 total,  2047996 free,        0 used. 14562068 avail Mem
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
I just discovered that some noteworthy processes do exist. I thought those InnoDB processes are regular, but I guess they are stuck somehow? (as to FILE I/O above)

```
| Id    | User        | Host      | db   | Command     | Time  | State                                                                 | Info                  | Progress |
+-------+-------------+-----------+------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
|     3 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon      |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker                                                   | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|     2 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon      |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker                                                   | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|     1 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon      |  NULL | InnoDB purge coordinator                                              | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|     4 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon      |  NULL | InnoDB purge worker                                                   | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|     5 | system user |           | NULL | Daemon      |  NULL | InnoDB shutdown handler                                               | NULL                  |    0.000 |
|    10 | slave-db2   | db2:39696 | NULL | Binlog Dump | 41840 | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL                  |    0.000 |
| 46369 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query       |     0 | Init                                                                  | show full processlist |    0.000 |
+-------+-------------+-----------+------+-------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+
```

**Edit 2:**
I wanted to let you know, the CPU usage back to normal, with no apparent reason. It seems server was occupied for the last 3 days, calculating who-knows-what, but I'm very glad it finished and everything seems ok again. I'll wait a little more time and free up more space, then I take another run on the InnoDB conversion.

Thank you @Rick James for your efforts.

Comment: What setting (`SHOW VARIABLES`) is at 64 or 128?

Comment: 64: innodb_autoextend_increment, innodb_read_io_threads, innodb_write_io_threads, max_error_count
128: innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency, innodb_rollback_segments, innodb_undo_logs, thread_cache_size

Comment: OK.  The list of I/O-threads is consistent with the 64 for %_io_threads settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Conversion**

InnoDB will use 2 to 3 times as much disk space as MyISAM.  That is one of the very few drawbacks of InnoDB (relative to MyISAM).

If you can start over with a bigger disk, that would be the best.

If you are in the middle of converting "in place" and are stuck, kill the process.  (It is unlikely to ever finish unless you can magically free some disk space.)  Then we can discuss what to do with the half-finished conversion.

Some more discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

**High CPU**

Connect to the database and do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  This _should_ tell us what is running (inside MySQL); that may give a clue of the CPU hog.  Assuming it is referring to some table, please provide` SHOW CREATE TABLE` for it.

Comment: Thanks, but the process that initially converted the table doesn't seem to exist anymore. But I discovered the InnoDB processes, not sure if they belong there.. (I updated my question above with the processlist)

Comment: @Nuramon - That PROCESSLIST looks 'normal'; the InnoDB processes run in the background.  I was hoping to see something other than those.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an explanation for the high CPU.

Comment: Apparently the CPU now went down by itself after 64 hours (see Edit #2 above). I really hope it stays this way. Thank you very much for your efforts!